# php update localstorage array without adding new array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add an array localstorage. works fine. I can also retrieve it . how can I.update where ID is something without adding a new array.
example ..
how can I go update surname and age where ID = sam  without creating new array

```
var objItem = {};
if (localstorage.getItem("records") == null) {
    objArr = [];
} else {
    objArr = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("records"));
}
var ID = "sam";
var surname = "edward";
var age = "two";
objItem.ID = ID;
objItem.surname = surname;
objItem.age = age;
objArr.push(objItem);
localstorage.setItem("records", JSON.stringify(objArr));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` is just a key-value store. To update, you just save to the same key. That is, you retrieve your array, parse, update, stringify then save to the same key.

To find the item on the array, you can use `array.filter` and create an array containing only the values that match the ID. Update the values inside that array and save the original array.

```
let names = [...names...];
let matches = names.filter(person => person.ID === ID);
matches.forEach(person => person.surname = surname);
let toSave = JSON.stringify(names);
// save to localstorage
```